# 10 year ban - what can be done to remove that ban?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-bans

I’ve got a 10 year Ban under paragraph 320 (7B)

Wrong information submitted by a traveller office in my country in my visitor visa led me to get the ban.

However,
I was unaware about the false documents related to my period of staying, financial status and other wrong details, written by the travel agency until I arrived at Heathrow airport on 12 Nov 2019 and was interviewed by an immigration officer.

I was returned to Saudi Arabia and they issued me a refusal letter and 10 year ban.

What can be done to remove a ban?

Comment: Add the refusal letter here as an image, blanking out your name and personal information - the content of that letter is extremely important to your question.

Comment: That's fairly serious. You really need an immigration lawyer

Comment: Waiting 10 years until it expires is one way to get rid of the ban...